# Can you configure dnsmasq/dhcpd to lease two IP ranges to Podman containers and libvirt VMs?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

For the past several days now, I've been trying to research and figure out how to setup two different IP ranges in the same network that only function as quick identifiers. Hardware-wise, I have the following:

- A variety of personal devices, which I will refer to as group A. They are addressed in the 192.168.0.1/24 subnet.
- A former desktop PC which will be the actual use case once that is ready, but for now testing the networking configuration on a VM running on my personal computer. This is a Fedora Server 38 running on Hyper-V, using a bridged virtual switch so as to appear as its own device on the network. In both situations, they are or will be running a combination of various containers (through Podman) and VMs (through libvirt). Both the machine/VM and its own containers/VM I will refer to as group B. I want every container and VM to appear on the network as individual clients, to be addressed on the 192.168.100.1/24 subnet.
- A very simple, old router (TP-Link Archer C9), on 192.168.0.1.

All I am trying to accomplish is that machines in group B appear on the network as their own machines, but in a different IP range than machines in group A, not for anything more than quick identification. So far I can accomplish the following:

- Group B host is outside of the DHCP range of the personal devices by assigning a static IP to it.
- Containers using a macvlan network will appear in the network directly with their own IP address
- VMs using a bridged virtual network will appear in the network directly with their own IP address

However, in respect to the containers and VMs IP addresses, they will use the DHCP configured on the router, which will assign them the same range of IP addresses as group A (192.168.0.100-192.168.0.199). I would prefer if they use a different one (e.g. 192.168.100.100-192.168.100-199) just for the sake of semantically separating the two.

I've tried a variety of things and researched quite a bit, but hitting a roadblock because this doesn't seem like an exactly common or worthwhile scenario - I'm not interested in segregating networks with VLANs or purchasing additional hardware (if it comes to that, I'll just live with everything in the same subnet). From my research, I've vaguely gathered the following information that may or may not pertain to setting this up:

- <s>I can setup static routing on my router, such that IP addresses that fall under a certain subnet (e.g. 192.168.100.1/24) will use a specific gateway. I imagine this should be configured to point to the IP address of the machine that represents group B, which I have done?</s>
- <s>I have to setup a DHCP server on the group B machine that represents the group B subnet?</s>
- <s>I need to configure both Podman and the libvirt virtual network to use the group B machine as a gateway and DHCP server?</s>
- dnsmasq and dhcpd both support different DHCP options based off criteria - dnsmasq with tags and dhcpd with classes
- In theory, I would want to use DHCP option 60 (vendor class identifier) to be sent out from both Podman and VMs to identify these requests uniquely and assign them different IP ranges
- In theory, Podman's macvlan network should use the DHCP settings of the host (through netavark's dhcp-proxy), but in practice, this doesn't seem to be working. That's to say, if I configure the host to send a vendor class identifier in its own request, Podman containers on a macvlan network don't seem to honor this.
- I can configure VMs directly to send the vendor class identifier, but ideally I'd like for it to be configured for all VMs that use the given network bridge. Configuring it on the network bridge doesn't seem to work for the VMs globally though.

<s>At this point I've tried all sorts of various different things that I've completely forgotten what exactly I've done and tried, except nothing has yet to work entirely. Either containers and VMs appear to have an IP in group B subnet but cannot be reached in any manner (either by the host group B machine or by other machines in the network), or they fail to lease an IP to begin with, or they just end up using the group A subnet.</s> (Not relevant as focusing efforts on DHCP options being sent in requests rather than two distinct DHCP servers.)

Is this even possible to begin with given the hardware at hand? I understand there's no practical purpose because I am not intending on any network segregation, I just thought it would look tidy.

Comment: You're needlessly complicating things by using separate subnets. That requires something to act as a router between the two subnets (yes, even if they are all on the same Ethernet LAN). If the secondary subnet needs Internet access, you'd also need a way to do NAT for that second subnet. Instead, why not just do different ranges of the same subnet? Group A gets addresses below 100, group B gets addresses 100 and above. Or use a /23 subnet (if your current router / NAT gateway allows it) so 192.168.0.x and 192.168.1.x are the same subnet, but .0.x means group A, and .1.x means group B.

Comment: Honestly that sounds perfectly fine but struggling how that would look at an architecture level?

My router can and has been setup actually to recognize 192.168.0.0/16 as it's LAN, but it's DHCP is only leasing to 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.199 (its default). How would I get a group B to be leased an different IP range (e.g. 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.199)? Would I still need a separate DHCP server for this?

Comment: Wait. Do you have a subnet mask mismatch between your router and your clients? Are you saying your router's using /16 but your clients are using /24?

Comment: I think I've misused subnet here, but no, the clients should be in /16. I think more accurately, what I should have said, is I want group A to be leased in a different IP range than group B. Based off further research I've done today, this might be possible with DHCP tags? Is this proper usage of them? If I understand correctly, I can set one IP range representing group B using a tag, and then need Podman and libvirt VMs configured such that their DHCP requests are tagged appropriately?

Comment: I think you should take a few steps back, look at the very original problem you are trying to solve, and then focus on finding the right solution to that problem. Multiple subnets isn't an illegal thing to do, but it doesn't sound like it is the best way to accomplish what you want. Frankly, if you're just trying to identify things in a particular way, using a standard for naming your computers and devices is the simplest and most effective way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I've rolled back on the multiple subnets thing. I think the best approach is configuring a DHCP server that leases different IP ranges based off criteria (e.g. dnsmasq tags or dhcpd classes). However, there doesn't appear to be a way to uniquely identify a Podman's DHCP request from anything else, and for VMs, it would need to be configured per individual VM as far as I can tell currently.